# list() returns different number of comments from a video

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-livestreaming-api

I'm trying to crawl comments of a given videoId with youtube API.
But the number of crawled comments is less than its actual number.
Do you have any idea about this? My code is like the below.

```py
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from typing import List

def get_comments(api, video_id: str, fields: str)-> List[List[str]]:
    comments = list()
    response = api.commentThreads().list(part='snippet', fields=fields, videoId=video_id, maxResults=50).execute()
    
    all_comment_crawled = True
    while all_comment_crawled:
        for item in response['items']:
            comment = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']
            comments.append([comment['textOriginal'], comment['likeCount']])

        if 'nextPageToken' in response:
            response = api.commentThreads().list(part='snippet', videoId=video_id, fields=fields, pageToken=response['nextPageToken'], maxResults=50).execute()
        else:
            all_comment_crawled = False
         
    return comments

api_key = "MY_API_KEY"
api_obj = build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=api_key)

video_id = 'fgSvGLxanCo'
fields = 'items(snippet(totalReplyCount, topLevelComment(snippet(textOriginal, likeCount)))), nextPageToken'

comments = get_comments(api_obj, video_id, fields)
print(len(comments)) # returns 1,945 actually is over 2,000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a trap (and I announce another trap that it is easy to fall into) when listing comments on a YouTube video:

1. The comments count on YouTube counts all (not filtered) comments. **The replies are included in this count** and you haven't considered them in your algorithm. Have a look to [CommentThreads: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list)
2. The replies when using `commentThreads` are given **up to 5 replies**.
   If the comment have more than 5 replies you have to use [Comments: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/comments/list) to list them all.

An example of Python script treating all comments of a video is available [here](https://codeberg.org/Benjamin_Loison/Search_in_YouTube_video_comments).

Comment: Oh, I see, the return of my code is the number of comments except for replies. Thanks a lot!