# YouTube Data API v3 get new comment list

Tags: youtube-data-api

How I get comments for video increments instead of all comments?

For example, can I get new comments for video from the notification list?

[YouTube search](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHlnB.png)

https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list

This activities API doesn't contain comment type.

Please help...

Expect I can know which comment are new and decide if I need to check out the comment for this video.

Comment: Are you interested in the new comments of a given video, or a given set of videos of a given channel, or a given set of videos of multiple channels?

Comment: Yes,It's exactly what I want to know.Please give me some advice.

Comment: I asked you above which proposition among 3 you are interested in, please tell me which proposition you are interested in.

Comment: Then [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71943981) and my answer solves your problem if you use the default parameter value [`order=time`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#order).