# YouTube API Code is Collecting Comments But Not Replies

Tags: python, youtube-api

I am a very beginner Python user. I am attempting to collect all comments from a YouTube video using the YouTube V3 API. My code is only giving me top level comments, and not replies. This is my first time using the YouTube API and I do not believe I have exceeded any quotas or rate limits.

My code is below. I have been inserting the API key and video ID in the appropriate place and still only receiving top level comments. I would appreciate any assistance as to where I may be going wrong. Thanks in advance!

```
import os
import csv
import googleapiclient.discovery

# Set your API key here
API_KEY = 'API KEY'

# Initialize the YouTube API client
youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build('youtube', 'v3', developerKey=API_KEY)

def get_all_comments(video_id):
    all_comments = []

    # Call the YouTube API to retrieve all comments (including replies)
    next_page_token = None
    while True:
        response = youtube.commentThreads().list(
            part='snippet',
            videoId=video_id,
            textFormat='plainText',
            pageToken=next_page_token
        ).execute()

        for item in response['items']:
            comment_data = item['snippet']['topLevelComment']['snippet']
            comment_data['authorDisplayName'] = comment_data['authorDisplayName']  # Username or Display Name
            comment_data['authorChannelId'] = comment_data.get('authorChannelId', {}).get('value', None)  # Channel ID (if available)
            all_comments.append(comment_data)

            # Collect replies to the top-level comment
            if 'replies' in item:
                for reply_item in item['replies']['comments']:
                    reply_data = reply_item['snippet']
                    reply_data['authorDisplayName'] = reply_data['authorDisplayName']  # Username or Display Name
                    reply_data['authorChannelId'] = reply_data.get('authorChannelId', {}).get('value', None)  # Channel ID (if available)
                    all_comments.append(reply_data)

        # Check if there are more comments to retrieve
        if 'nextPageToken' in response:
            next_page_token = response['nextPageToken']
        else:
            break
    
    return all_comments

def save_comments_to_csv(comments, file_path):
    with open(file_path, 'w', encoding='utf-8', newline='') as csvfile:
        fieldnames = comments[0].keys()  # Use the keys from the first comment as fieldnames
        csv_writer = csv.DictWriter(csvfile, fieldnames=fieldnames)
        csv_writer.writeheader()
        
        for comment in comments:
            csv_writer.writerow(comment)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    video_id = 'video_id'
    comments = get_all_comments(video_id)
    
    custom_location = 'Test Test Custom Path'
    save_comments_to_csv(comments, custom_location)
    
    print(f"Total comments collected: {len(comments)}")
    print(f"Comments saved to '{custom_location}'")
```

Comment: [This naswer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71284334) might help you.

Comment: Thanks! I changed the code from 
response = youtube.commentThreads().list( 

to 

response = youtube.comments().list(` 

and received TypeError: Got an unexpected keyword argument videoId

Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: For details about my answer consider [this repository](https://codeberg.org/Benjamin_Loison/Search_in_YouTube_video_comments).