# Youtube Data API incomplete comments collection #youtube-data-api

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

We are using the Youtube Data API to monitor the performances of our videos and collect the comments on each published video. We have noticed that the number of comments collected via the API are less than what we can see in the studio.youtube.com

The following example can help :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T1t6f2KqJ-o
The API return 21 comments while we can see 45 comments in the studio.

The used request is :
https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?maxResults=50&videoId=T1t6f2KqJ-o

It is reproducible in the API explorer in the following link : https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list?hl=fr&apix_params=%7B%22maxResults%22%3A50%2C%22videoId%22%3A%22T1t6f2KqJ-o%22%7D

Is there a way to have the complete list of comments?

Thank you in advance,
Yasmine

#youtube-api #youtube-data-api #youtube-v3-api

We tried to get the comments via this endpoint: https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/commentThreads?maxResults=50&videoId=T1t6f2KqJ-othe
The expected result is 45 comments but we only got 21 comments.

Comment: It seems you forgot to list at least 23 [`replies`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/commentThreads/list#part). I have given more details about this common mistake in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71284334). By the way I appreciate Brut videos.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminLoison, but I don't have 23 replies on this video, there's only 5 replies so I don't think that using Comments : list in this case will resolve my problem.

Comment: Does the YouTube Studio only state the video number of comments or does it provides them as well? If so, please share the comments you have access to for this video, such that I try to find what is wrong. To be honest I am quite surprised that YouTube Studio states such a gap, YouTube Data API v3 Videos: list endpoint only mentions 25 comments. Maybe if YouTube Studio does not provide the comments themselves it is inventing comments due to a bug or whatsoever.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison it provides them as well, but today it shows only 25 comments as you said. I'm pretty sure there was 45 comments a few weeks ago. Maybe some comments were deleted and there was a delay in the update between the studio and what the API returns. Thank you for your help.